# Expiration Alert email

Tags: workflow, email, alert

I need to write design a SPD workflow that send email to the person based on expiry date. The workflow should automatically update when the expiry date is updated. I have been working with post by Mr. Andrey in the below link, but some items are not clearly mentioned.

http://markeev.com/Articles/item-expiration-reminders-in-sharepoint-using-workflow.aspx

Please some body help me out with this.

Comment: What you are unclear of? Which step/activity?

Comment: Hi Mr. Aman, I am having confusion about the 4th line, ie 'Set current item: previous due date not equal to current item due date'-how did he calculate the previous due date. i got the logic.

Comment: You can ignore that field and remove the reference from the workflow. I don't see any use of the field.

Comment: So,how this work flow will work..i think this is checking for any change in the actual due date,if i am wrong,please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Previous Due Date is a date time field that you should add to the list. This field is used by the workflow.

Comment: If so,how we will get the previous date colomn. Do we need to add the previous date?

Comment: The link you posted in the question has a Previous Due Date column, but its of no use. This field is not updated any where so it will always have an empty value.

Comment: Sorry to ask again,in the next step it is updating the due date right?

Comment: If possible,,can you give me the corrected workflow..am a beginer..you outmost help is appreciated

Comment: Dear Mr. Amal,please can you give me a better solution for this. Thanks in advance.